# Can I push my git submodules to Github without using extra repositories?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have a Github "Gold" account and I'm starting to run out of my allotted repositories. :-(

Luckily, I have a few very small projects that are interrelated and could be treated as submodules of a bigger project. I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to submodules, so forgive me if my question is naive...

I'd like to push the supermodule along with all of its submodules into one Github repository if that's possible. This would help me conserve my remaining Github repositories for projects that are truly separate. Can I do this?

In my investigation of the problem so far it looks like each submodule needs to have its own remote, and if that's the case then I'll run out of repositories before long!

Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you're right. Each submodule is it's own complete repository. So it needs an extra repository to be able to share.